# Route finding on a graph that must go through multiple edges

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal, traveling-salesman, routing

I have this graph

[image]

It shows a graph of a map that has nodes and segments (or edges), with weights, that connect these nodes. Some of these segments have addresses on, and some of these addresses are designated as restaurants. There are two chosen restaurants, and one chosen address.

Can someone point me in the direction of an algorithm that would calculate the best path to get from any segment, through each of the segments containing the chosen restaurants, and ending at the chosen address?

So far I have looked at Christofides Algorithm, and Dijkstra's Algorithm, neither of which seem to solve this problem, or atleast i cannot work out how to alter the algorithms to make them work for this problem.

Comment: For such a small instance, you can probably solve this exactly using integer programming.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus i know, but this is just a smaller example of a much larger application

Comment: Practically speaking, I would just run a known TSP algorithm and remove the edge touching the chosen endpoint. There is also a reduction from your problem to TSP that I gave in comments to your two preceding posts, but it loses the planar nature of your problem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What do you mean by the planar nature of my problem, and a reduction _from_ my problem _to_ TSP, i don't want to use TSP right as it necessitates a closed circuit?

Comment: Your points live on the Euclidean plane, and this potentially makes your problem easier to solve (compared to a general metric).

Comment: The reduction enables you to solve your problem *using* a solver for TSP. Since solvers for TSP do exist, this is potentially useful for you.

Comment: I don't think a TSP solver will be useful here as ultimately I'm trying to implement an algorithm into an application. Also - would removing the edge touching the chosen endpoint not be fairly inaccurate? Since a TSP algorithm would make the n-1 node in the circuit as close to the starting node as possible.

Comment: You can use a TSP solver as part of a larger application. Indeed, I suspect that this is typically how a TSP solver is used. There are many open-source TSP solvers you could use.

Comment: Running a TSP solver and removing an edge might result in some loss in accuracy, but it is a reasonable heuristic. The other option is to use the reduction to TSP which I have been mentioning.

Comment: It would really help if you could ballpark the number of chosen restaurants.  It should be very doable to have up towards 15 restaurants with the classic DP algorithm.  If you accept approximation algorithms, you can get a much faster algorithm handling hundreds of restaurants (as @YuvalFilmus says, on the plane).

Comment: @PålGD I understand what you're saying, but every time i do research on TSP, i see that algorithms that solve TSP give a closed circuit, but i don't want a closed circuit.

Answer (score 1):

I have decided that the best solution to this is a variation on Dijkstra's algorithm. Since it doesn't require a Hamiltonian Circuit and makes it easy to manage the weights. I will also use Homeomorphism as suggested in the comments of the question to make weighting the distance between the nodes and addresses more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The statement that you want a path that "goes through multiple edges" is easily replaced with a normal path finding algorithm when you observe that you can *subdivide each edge* containing a place of interest.

Subdividing an edge $e = uv$ means that you create a new vertex $v_e$ with $u$ and $v$ as neighbors, and then you delete the edge $e$ from the resulting graph.  If the edges are weighted, there should be no issue in putting $w(e)/2$ on each of the two new edges (depending a bit on what the weights mean).

Once you have done that, the problem is a standard [Euclidean TSP problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Euclidean).  There are many approximation algorithms (a very simple 2-approximation using minimum spanning trees), as well as numerous [PTAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme) algorithms.

In the case where you only have a handful of, say, "terminals" (your restaurants), the very easily implementable classic exact DP algorithm running in $O(2^t t^2 \cdot (n+m))$ time should be very feasible (say for $t \leq 12$).